# Dividing the values by their mean for many variables

Tags: transform, spss, data-transform

I wish to conduct a data Transformation by dividing each case in a variable by that variable's mean. I have 91 variables in my dataset. I create the means using the AGGREGATE function:

```
  AGGREGATE
  /OUTFILE=* MODE = ADDVARIABLES
  /BREAK=
  /mean_1 to mean_91= MEAN(Var1 TO Var91).
```

This code is giving me each variable's mean in the same dataset, but in order to divide each case by its mean, I have created a new dataset with a command that can repeat itself. The Problem is to Change from mean_1 to mean_2 ...... mean_91.

`COMPUTE CMD = CONCAT("COMPUTE",RTRIM(Name),".Norm =",RTRIM(Name),"/mean",1,".").`

How can i make sure that in the next line, the number 1 will become 2, then 3 and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a much simpler way to accomplish your task. After calculating the means like you did, you can loop through all the variables like this:

```
do repeat vr=var1 to var91 /mn=mean_1 to mean_91 /nrm=norm1 to norm91.
   compute nrm=vr/mn.
end repeat.
```

Comment: Do not forget `EXECUTE.` at the very end :)

Comment: Well, that's a question - when answering questions in SO I has a couple of cases where the OP thought my code didn't work because I didn't include an `exe.` and they didn't know they need to run transformation. But on the other hand, putting an `exe.` after every command is not good practice, and I don't want to contribute to bad habits among SPSS beginners. So what I do is *not* include it in the syntax, and if the OP doesn't figure it out by themselves I explain (or send them to explanations like [this one](https://www.spss-tutorials.com/spss-execute-command/))